# Convert simple postgreSQL function to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, linux, postgresql

I was wondering if I could get some help. I have the following function in Postgresql which is designed to give me a "solrid" value without having to store it each time in the database, and basically works by putting an "A" at the start of the value.

```
-- Setup Solrid Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION solrid(IN local_id INTEGER, OUT result TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
    database_id TEXT := 'A';
BEGIN
    result := database_id || local_id::TEXT;
END;
 $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I now have to move my database to MySql and I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can convert this function to work with MySQL.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected result?

Comment: Just FYI, that doesn't need to be written in PL/PgSQL, the simple SQL function would be `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION solrid(integer) RETURNS text AS $$ SELECT 'A'||$1; $$ LANGUAGE SQL` . This would be a heck of a lot faster and could often be inlined away.

Comment: It is a way of getting my job table "id" into a solr_id without having to store the solr_id. The job "id" might be 123 and the solr_id would be A123.

Comment: Craig can you add this as an answer please?

Comment: @CraigRinger Also, can you explain where it references the initial ID? I,e where is the table jobs "id"?

Comment: See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL

Comment: I tried the online converters linked to on that page but they dont seem to work

Comment: @Jimmy I didn't post as an answer because that's still PostgreSQL syntax, not MySQL. It might simplify porting to MySQL, but it's really a cleanup of the PostgreSQL function not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same function in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS solrid //

CREATE FUNCTION solrid(local_id INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE database_id TEXT;
  SET database_id = 'A';
  RETURN CONCAT(database_id, CAST(local_id AS CHAR));
END //

DELIMITER ;
```